# Understanding available Vaadin 7 Widgets/addons 'GWT'

Tags: rest, gwt, vaadin, vaadin7, confluence-rest-api

From my understanding Vaadin consumes GWT and adds an engine on the browser end to interact with server side UI.  In looking for a 'Confluence' Vaadin add on I came up with nothing.  I would like to use Javascript instead of Vaadin pure Java to talk with Confluence 'rest'.  However I believe that I found find some GWT Confluence plugins.  Since Vaadin uses GWT already do you think a GWT confluence plugin is the way to go?  Also there is a angularjs/vaadin addon and then I could us angularjs with Confluence.  Your thoughts please...

Answer (score 1):

The traditional [Vaadin Framework](https://vaadin.com/framework) consists of a java backend on the server and components which are rendered on client side. Most of those are client side rendering are written with Java/GWT.

In addition to this, there exist the [Vaadin Elements](https://vaadin.com/elements), which are "pure" JS components for the frontend.

[Is Vaadin Elements meant to be used with the Vaadin Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992084/is-vaadin-elements-meant-to-be-used-with-the-vaadin-framework/39998617?noredirect=1#comment67360050_39998617)

If you wish to write a app with all logic client side (And perhaps calling some REST api), then you will need to write this in JS (perhaps with Angular/Polymer etc.).
In that case you could use the vaadin elements for some of the tasks, but you will remain in the JS world.

To answer your question:
Using a GWT thing and combining it with JS isn't the most up-to-date way to handle things.
GWT makes sense when you wish to write frontend code with Java but certainly not for JS.