# How to write vaadin dynamic grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid, vaadin4spring

Does anybody know how to build a dynamic vaadin grid like here:
https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-grid/2.0.0-alpha3/demo/data.html#dynamic-height

It is strange because I have never seen that vaadin allow to write code as it is in the link above. Where to put this template? Is it possible that in a standard vaadin code?

Comment: Since Vaadin Grid relies on JavaBean, I think you should check out the apache commons BeanUtils. It has features such as DynaBean and DynaClass which are amazingly creates dynamic JavaBean. Then you can put the Beans on a list and grid.setItems(theList). Well, I haven't tried this for real. So, good luck and happy research!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the demo page for [Vaadin Grid Element](https://vaadin.com/elements/vaadin-grid/), not the [Grid](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid) from Vaadin Framework.

Grid element is a part of so-called [Vaadin Elements](https://vaadin.com/elements) - set of client-side widgets which can be used from other javascript frameworks (e.g. React, Angular, etc.).

Vaadin released Elements separately from their Framework, so in order to use them from a traditional Vaadin application, you'll need to take additional steps. See this blog post for the detailed walkthrough: [Using Vaadin Elements with Vaadin Framework](https://vaadin.com/blog/using-vaadin-elements-with-vaadin-framework).

You also might want to look through this similar question: [Is Vaadin Elements meant to be used with the Vaadin Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39992084/is-vaadin-elements-meant-to-be-used-with-the-vaadin-framework).